# undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method EmpNbr) error

Tags: go

Below is my code:

Step 1: model folder

```
type EmployeeWithRoot struct {
    Employee []Employee
}

type Employee struct {
    EmpNbr     sql.NullString  `json:"EmpNbr"`
    DateofJoin      sql.NullString   `json:"DateofJoin"`
        DeptId  sql.NullString  `json:"DeptId"`
        DeptName sql.NullString  `json:"DeptName"`
}
```

Step 2: code folder

```
func GetEmpDetails(logRequestId string, logNestedLevel int, EmpNbr string, DateofJoin string) ([]model.EmployeeWithRoot, error) {

    logFunctionFunctionName := "code.GetEmpDetails"
    logStartTime := time.Now()
    logNestedLevel++

    defer configurations.TimeTrack(logFunctionFunctionName, logRequestId, logStartTime, logNestedLevel)

    rows, err := db.Query(utils.SELECT_OF_EMP_AGGR, EmpNbr, DateofJoin, DeptId, DeptName)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var e []model.EmployeeWithRoot

    for rows.Next() {
        var x model.EmployeeWithRoot
        err := rows.Scan(&x.Employee.EmpNbr, &x.Employee.DateofJoin, &x.Employee.DeptId,&x.Employee.DeptName)

        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        e = append(e, x)
    }

    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return e, nil
}
```

STEP 3: API folder

```
Employee, err := code.GetEmpDetails(logRequestId, logNestedLevel, EmpNbr, DateofJoin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    marshalDataForRequestContentType(logRequestId, logNestedLevel, w, r, Employee)
```

I'm new to go-lang and getting the below error. Can any one please take a look and assist me what line of the code am I missing?

x.Employee.EmpNbr undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method EmpNbr)
x.Employee.DateofJoin undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method DateofJoin)
x.Employee.DeptId undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method DeptId)
x.Employee.DeptName undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method DeptName)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```golang
var x model.EmployeeWithRoot
err := rows.Scan(&x.Employee.EmpNbr, &x.Employee.DateofJoin, &x.Employee.DeptId,&x.Employee.DeptName)
```

`x.Employee` is a slice: `[]Employee` as you define it in the model.

You are trying to call `.EmpNbr` on a slice so that obviously doesn't work.

This would work:

```golang
var x model.Employee
err := rows.Scan(&x.EmpNbr, &x.DateofJoin, &x.DeptId,&x.DeptName)
```

Comment: The reason I've model.EmployeeWithRoot is because of the below desired json response(appended with root element Employee in quotes). We need two variables one for appending root element to json and the other for retrieving final json response. How can I achieve this with the current version of my code?                                                                               {
 {  "Employee":[
      {
         "EmpId":{
            "String":"ABCD",
            "Valid":true
         },
         "DateofJoin":{
            "String":"ABCD",
            "Valid":true
        }
   ]
}

Comment: you can always declare `var er model.EmployeeRoot` and then after you scan the row do `er.Employee = append(er.Employee, x)`. Not the most efficient but it would get the job done. And then you can still do `e = append(e, er)

Comment: With the code mentioned in Step2, I get x.Employee.EmpNbr undefined (type []model.Employee has no field or method EmpNbr) . Am I missing anything?

Comment: you are still talking about your original code so yes you are missing my solution.